# Calling a QListWidgetItem method gives a "TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable" message

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyqt, qt-signals

I subclassed a `QListWidget` (named `List`) which has a `pyqtSignal` named `dataChanged` that is emitted in another baseclass `DataWidget`. Actually everything works, **but**

if the methods `setForeground` or `setTooltip` of an item (`QListWidgetItem`) in the `List` are called, I get this

```
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

message. Another `pyqtSignal` named `itemLeft` of the `List` class if emitted not in a baseclass but in the `List` class itself and does not have the problem.

So, what I'd like to know is:

- Why does this message appear when calling a method of a listitem?
  How come calling a method is related to that signal?!
- What is wrong with the code? / What do I need to change?

Here is a MWE to reproduce it.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QFormLayout, QListWidget,
                         QListWidgetItem, QColor)
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class DataWidget(object):
    """ A widget to drop data """
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        """ Emits the dataChanged signal """
        # actions to be taken on drop
        self.dataChanged.emit()

class List(QListWidget, DataWidget):
    """ List widget used for, e. g. features  """
    # This signal makes no problems
    itemLeft = pyqtSignal()
    # but this one does
    dataChanged = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(List, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.itemLeft.emit()


class ApplicationWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # The ListWidget
        self.list = List(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.list)

        self.list.itemLeft.connect(self.doOnItemLeft)
        self.list.dataChanged.connect(self.doOnDrop)

        # Adding an item to self.list
        item = QListWidgetItem('List Item Name', self.list)

        textcolor, tooltip = QColor(), None
        textcolor.setRgb(50, 50, 115)
        tooltip = 'Tool tip'
        # Calling following methods gives causes
        # TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
        print('calling: QListWidgetItem.setForeground() for', str(item.text()))
        item.setForeground(textcolor)
        print('calling: QListWidgetItem.setToolTip() for', str(item.text()))
        item.setToolTip(tooltip)

    def doOnItemLeft(self):
        # make gui adaptions...
        print('Widget left')

    def doOnDrop(self):
        # get data from widget and so on...
        pass

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = ApplicationWindow()

win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Version

```
>>> PyQt4.pyqtconfig.Configuration().pyqt_version_str
'4.9.6'
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but QAbstractItemView::dataChanged() is virtual protected slot, so you cannot call it on your list widget.

Comment: Right, QAbstractItemView has the slot dataChanged(), so naming your signal the same will cause issues. Give it a different name.

Comment: @vahancho that seems to fix it, good hint. Still I wonder, why this message comes up, when a QListWidgetItem method is being called. Should I delete the question now due to insignificance or would somebody make that an answer?

Comment: @frankosterfeld that seems to fix it, good hint. Still I wonder, why this message comes up, when a QListWidgetItem method is being called. Should I delete the question now due to insignificance or would somebody make that an answer?

Comment: embert: My guess would be that some internal code tries to call the dataChanged() slot, but as you added the signal, it tries to call the signal instead. (Just a guess).

Comment: I think it is a good question, don't delete it. If Vahancho or Osterfeld could make this an answer that would be nice. Otherwise feel free to do so yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vahancho and Osterfeld identified, the issue is that `QListWidget` inherits from `QAbstractItemView`, which defines a protected slot called "dataChanged": the slot is called when items are changed in the model, thereby allowing the derived class (`QListWidget` in this case) to take action.

Hence creating a signal of the same name does not make sense. Calling methods `setForeground` or `setTooltip` on the list item causes the slot to be called, only the slot has been overridden by a signal, leading to the observed error.